# Individual bicycle data within a bike hire scheme

Tags: api, public-transport, bikesharing

Does anyone know of a bicycle hire scheme anywhere in the world that provides individual bicycle data within its API?

For example, the Barclays Cycle Hire scheme in London provides data on each bike rack in this form:

Bike rack ID:  1234
Number of slots: 10
Number of bikes: 3
Number of empty slots: 7

But do any systems provide the ID numbers for individual bikes on a rack?  E.g

Number of bikes: 3
Slot 1: Bike ID #3012
Slot 2: Bike ID #4067
Slot 3: Bike ID #6639
Etc

Answer (score 4):

[Capital Bikeshare](http://www.capitalbikeshare.com/trip-history-data) has this. [CitiBike](http://www.meetup.com/betanyc/events/121671282/) seems to as well.

Also, [CityBikes](http://api.citybik.es/) looks really cool.

Answer (score 0):

[Social Bicycles](https://app.socialbicycles.com/developer/#!/bikes/GET_bikes_format_get_0), which operates bikes shares [in the US, Canada, and Australia](http://socialbicycles.com/#where).

https://app.socialbicycles.com/developer/